# How to use setup.py and setup.cfg and pip-tools to obtain layered requirements.txt under different environment of a Django project?

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

I'm using https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools to handle compiling the requirements.txt file for a Django project.

Previously, I was using it without a setup.py, and so I was using base.in, local.in, and production.in.

When I needed a local requirements.txt, after I finished running `pip-compile`, I just ran `pip-sync base.txt local.txt`, and it installed the requirements for the local environment.

When I needed a production requirements.txt, after I finished running `pip-compile`, I just ran `pip-sync base.txt production.txt`, and it installed the requirements for the production environment.

So, I switched away from using base.in, because I wanted to also lock the Python version and I realized setup.py and setup.cfg can help using `python_requires`.

But now I've become unsure of how to use setup.py and setup.cfg along with pip-tools to compile requirements.txt that can be environment-specific.

The only documentation for layered requirements is by using the different .in files as written in the README as in: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements

So, my question is, with the following components:

1. pip-tools
2. setup.py and setup.cfg

How to still have layered requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip-tools` works smoothly with `setup.py` too. You just need to run it without providing it with an `*.in` file.

## Mixed variant with setup.py and in files:

So assuming, that you have the following structure:

```
# setup.py replacing the base.in file
from distutils.core import setup


setup(
    name="MyLibrary",
    version="1.0",
    install_requires=[
        "requests",
        "bcrypt",
    ]
)
```

and a local.in file:

```
django
```

you need to do the following to compile the dependencies:

```
$ pip-compile -o base.txt 
$ pip-compile local.in
$ pip-sync base.txt local.txt
```

`$ pip-compile -o base.txt` will generate dependencies from `setup.py` using `base.txt` as an output file. It defaults to `requirements.txt`.
`$ pip-compile local.in` is the same what you did before, as with the `pip-sync` part which doesn't change.

So the only magic here is to run `pip-compile` without providing it with an input file.

## Setup.py only solution:

Setup.py supports `extras_require` which is a dictionary of named optional dependencies:

```
[...]
    extras_require={
        "local": ["pytest"],
    },
[...]
```

pip-tools has an option `extra`:

```
$ pip-compile --help |grep extra
  --extra TEXT     Name of an extras_require group to install;
```

So you could do the following:

```
pip-compile --extra local -o local.txt
pip-compile --extra production -o production.txt
```

The output files contain all requiremenets in `install_requires` + the extra requirements specified.

Afterwards you just sync the local/production.txt:

```
$ pip-sync local.txt
$ pip-sync production.txt
```

If I was you, I would grab the pure setup.py variant.

Comment: Thank you  this is more like it! I wish the original website supported this kind of documentation

Comment: I’m on mobile phone but will try your answer once back on laptop. Yes agree I think I will pick the pure setup.py way

Comment: Actually all of this is documented: https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/#requirements-from-setuppy tells you how to use pip-compile with setup.py. If you write `$ pip-compile --help` on the console, you will find out the option about the extras, the way I found it.

Comment: Oh  I must have missed it. My bad 

Comment: Hi, @KimStacks, were you able to test the solution? Is it working as expected?

Comment: Sorry something else went wrong and i am not sure why. i will give you the 100 points first. if you can help me with this other issue, that would be great. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089578/i-keep-having-subprocess-calledprocesserror-while-trying-to-run-pip-compile-for

Comment: works exactly like you said.... you're really good. i hope you have a twitter or github or a blog i can follow 