# I keep getting subprocess.CalledProcessError while trying to run pip-compile for pip-tools

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

This is my code at [github](https://github.com/simkimsia/test-setup-py/commit/4e8ace18cc79984b4d313a09e2c71498453dedf8)

I am trying to test layered requirements for setup.py using pip-tools, and I keep getting issues with this error related to `subprocess.CalledProcessError`.

I am not sure what I've done wrong. Below is the asciicast:

[image: asciicast]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide us with your setup.py file? I am pretty sure that you have an error in it and this is why you are getting this message.

Comment: Oh, there is link to github, I've missed. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this kind of error is emitted (as far as I saw it several times) when your setup.cfg or setup.py are broken.

In your case, your extras are not defined properly. You should change your setup.cfg like the following:

```
[options]
python_requires = >=3.8
setup_requires = setuptools_scm
packages = find:
zip_safe = false
install_requires =
    # direct dependencies
    # pep517 ~= 0.12
    pip-tools ~= 6.5
    pip ~= 21.3
    # indirect dependencies
    # setuptools ~= 60.8  # typically needed when pip-tools invokes setup.py
    # wheel ~= 0.37 # pip plugin needed by pip-tools

[options.extras_require]
    local = pytest
```

Comment: oh it works! thanks, do you have a blog or twitter or github account i can follow so i can learn from your output?

Comment: actually are you the author of https://github.com/wankata/python-github-api-client? i happen to have a few questions about github api and i also use python. i have subscribed to enterprise support but they don't respond as complete an answer as you do here. can i ask you? if payment is needed, we can discuss.

Comment: Yes, this is my github account, but the repo you are looking at is just an interview task and I don't really maintain it.
If you are looking for a real github api client, take a look at those two projects:
[ghapi](https://ghapi.fast.ai/), [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub)
PS: I have twitter, but I have many different interests beyond Python and I am not only writing in English, so it will be more noise for you, than an interesting account to follow.

Comment: Oh I see that’s cool  thanks for responding. I was too excited perhaps. I have submitted PR at pygithub but they yet to merge and I have other questions and even now trialing GitHub paid support. But their response is not the best. So I’m on the lookout for more help in this area. Regardless thanks 